# Need to display dynamically created tables side by side horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a tables dynamically using following code.

```
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        txt.push("<table  class='tb1'; >");
        txt.push("<tr><td class='tb2'; width='50%'>"+list2[i][0]+"</td><td class='tb2'; width='50%'>"+list2[i][1]+"</td></tr>");
        txt.push("</table>");   
    }
    $('#divOutputArea').append(txt);
```

while displaying all tables appear one below the other vertically. can any one help me display all tables side by side horizontally using above code. appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your css: 
**table.tb1{display: inline-block;}** 
Works fine for me.

Comment: tried it, doesn't work. any other way please..

my CSS: <style>
table.tb1 { display: inline-table;; background-color: '#808080'; padding: 10px; table-layout: fixed; border: thin solid; border-collapse: collapse; float: left;}
td.tb2 { align:center; padding: 10px; border: solid; border-collapse: collapse;}
.tablecontainer { float: left;}
</style>

Comment: in table.tb1{ display: inline-table;; } you got 2 semicolons, maybe this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
table.tb1 {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

or insert each tables within floating divs:

HTML

```
<div class="tablecontainer">
<table>
...
</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tablecontainer {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: my CSS
'<style>
table.tb1 { display: inline-table;; background-color: '#808080'; padding: 10px; table-layout: fixed; border: thin solid; border-collapse: collapse; float: left;}
td.tb2 { align:center; padding: 10px; border: solid; border-collapse: collapse;}
.tablecontainer { float: left;}
</style>'

my div: 
<div  class="tablecontainer" id="outputArea">
 
</div>

doesn't work

Comment: if you use `inline-table` you don't need `.tablecontainer`. I wrote 2 different options you can use.

Comment: it is working for static pages, but I'm creating table using javascript.

Comment: replace your javascript for loop with this:     for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        txt.push("<table  class='tb1'>");
        txt.push("<tr><td class='tb2' style='width: 50%'>"+list2[i][0]+"</td><td class='tb2' style='width: 50%'>"+list2[i][1]+"</td></tr>");
        txt.push("</table>");   
    }